# Generate same data multiple times in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How do I generate same data multiple times in a table like in a loop using SQL script. I tried using `generate_series` but that does not seem to work.

```
INSERT into cars (name, type) VALUES select ('BMW', 'Sedan') from generate_series(1,50)
```

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were there! The syntax is not right. You should be doing this instead.

```
INSERT INTO cars (name, type) 
SELECT 'BMW', 'Sedan' 
FROM generate_series(1,50)
```

From [PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html),

> `generate_series(start, stop)` generates a series of values, from start to stop with a step size of one